# C# Dynamically keep recent objects in memory and load the olders when needed

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, clipboard

I need to monitor clipboard and build a list of past clips. The problem is that i need to keep as much clips as possible. While small text or filedrops are inexpensive, a large image can occupy a large chunk of memory, for example a 20MP image copied into clipboard.

My plan is to save clips into `SQLite`, while user navigate forward or backward in clipboard, a list in memory is dynamically built for a faster preview (Not have to wait for the `SQL Query`, and load a image for example).
A `pagination` system can be other solution.

I wonder if there are any kind of library that do this kind of job, something like a cache with `memory management` at same time or a better approach to this problem

Comment: you can use Dictionary to hold it or dynamically put the pagination in the SQL Query. according to the pages you should take values from db.

Comment: This is too broad a question and is considered off topic "asking to recommend a book, tool or library", you should try to narrow the focus of your question to something concrete and ask several separate questions to help you finish your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you're trying to prematurely optimize without actually testing performance. Get your solution working before you even bother trying to come up with clever ways to conserve memory.

Next, try out several some of the strategies you've outlined for managing memory and measure each. Decide which trade off you'd rather live with.

The simplest would be to just leave everything in memory (in an array), have a memory limit setting, track the size of each item being added, and truncate the oldest items until the item being added can fit.